# What is the meaning of this reputation showing +2 in the top tag area?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I want to know what the meaning of this reputation is. It was showing on the left side of the tag and can be seen in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you hover your mouse over that number you should see a tooltip with the following text:

> Reputation gained on this tag since your last visit to the reputation tab

Which should answer your question.

A screenshot to prove it's not fake news:

[image]

Comment: Is there any place where I can see the list of reputation increasing and decressing by tags?

Comment: Mean every tag how much reputation have.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3374681/a-raza?tab=tags) @A.Raza? Also see the "Tags" section on your profile's "Summary" tab [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3374681/a-raza?tab=summary).

Comment: Here is two values `5 php × 7` left mean total votes on tag, and right number of posts, where is reputation?

Comment: The "5" is the total score. That is, the total number of upvotes that your PHP answers have received. So that's 5 × 10 = 50 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

It is your top tag

**You gain reputation last visit to the reputation tab:**

•   one of your questions is voted up: +5

•   one of your answers is voted up: +10

•   one of your answers is accepted: +15

•   you accept an answer written by someone else to one of your own questions: +2

•   someone removes their downvote on one of your questions or answers: +2

•   you suggest an edit and it is approved: +2 (up to a total of +1000 per user)

•   you remove a downvote from an answer or an answer you downvoted is deleted: +1

•   one of your answers is awarded a bounty by the user offering the bounty: +full bounty amount

•   one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +½ of the bounty amount

•   you associate accounts between two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of once per site)